# calling particluar function after delay in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

how do I call a particular function after delay in java?

```
{

// Do something 

   callmeafterevery10sec () // call this function in every 10 sec while continue the whole thing 

 // Do something

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a Job for a ScheduledExecutorService. You should have a look at the JavaDoc for this class. There are great examples.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}, 0, 10000);
```

This will print `Hello World` every 10 seconds. You can use this inside a method, or use this to call another method.

**Option 2:**

From Brian Goetz et al.'s *Java Concurrency in Practice*, `ScheduledExecutorService` is better:

```
Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

More on ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Comment: @parikshitparmar, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: First solution doesn't work  it got stucked in the run method. Can't execute other method simultaneously .

Comment: Can you edit and put in the question what you have just tried? I will try to take a look at it. Because it is working for me.

Comment: import java.util.Timer; 
import java.util.TimerTask; 

class TestThread {

   public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws InterruptedException {
    Timer t = new Timer();
   
      System.out.println("First Print");
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           printSomething();
        }
    }, 0, 100);
    System.out.print("Last Print");
   
  }

  public static void printSomething(){
    System.out.print("Inside It ");
  }

}

Comment: I tried to edit my post but it's seems impossbile for me at this time i am new to add code and it shows that press ctrl +k  and 4 space indentetion

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60175366/edit) the question and add your code there using the `code` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just Call Thread.sleep(),it would work:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {    
        useTimer();
    }

    private static void useTimer() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("**********");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("----------");

    }
}
```

Comment: @parikshitparmar if this works then please accept the answer , otherwise just let me know if still facing the issue

Comment: A comment in the OP's example said, "call this function in every 10 sec while continue the whole thing." That sounds very much as if they want to perform a periodic task in a _background thread_.